# Natural Logarithms (Help)

Tags: logarithms

Can I have an answer with working out to this question please, I am puzzled at the result I got and don't believe it is right. The question asks to 'Simplify by expressing as a single natural logarithm'.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-3\ln3+2\ln9-2\ln81=-3\ln3+\ln81-2\ln81=-3\ln3-\ln81=-3\ln3-4\ln3=-7\ln3=\ln\frac{1}{2187}$